# Why is に used with causativeて+もらう but not causativeて +くれる?

Tags: grammar, particles, causation

**Example:**

> 両親**が**一人で日本に行かせてくれた

> My parents let me go to Japan alone

*And*

> 両親**に**一人で日本に行かせてもらった

> My parents let me go [after me asking] to Japan alone

Comment: it’s 両親が...くれた and 両親に...もらった.

Comment: what i meant by that comment was that 両親 gets parsed with the verbs くれる/もらう and not the verb in the causative, いかせて. though really they both go hand in hand however the grammar of が vs に is driven by the verb of giving or receiving expressed, not the causative.

Comment: I think you need to step back a little and first learn the basics of that grammar くれる/もらう and then start adding it to てform, causatives, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

くれる basically means "to give", and もらう basically means "to receive". Let's think about this with simpler examples:

- 両親が私**に**本をくれた。
  My parents gave a book **to** me.
- 私は両親**に**本をもらった。
  (= 私は両親**から**本をもらった。)
  I received a book **from** my parents.

In the former, the subject is 両親, and in the latter, the subject is 私. Both has に, but these two に play different roles. When you use もらう, the に-marked argument marks the **giver**. This is a basic rule of how もらう works.

Now, if we replace 本を with 一人で日本に行かせて, we get these:

- 両親が(私**に**)一人で日本に行かせてくれた。
- (私は)両親**に**一人で日本に行かせてもらった。
  <sub>(両親から no longer works because no physical object is transferred.)</sub>

These are the sentences you are asking about. In the latter, you can see the に-marked argument still marks the **giver** (of favor).